# Calculating price after sales commission and discount

Tags: java, finance

The code already works, but I just want tips for improving.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Calculator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double initialPrice = 0.00;
        double commissionRate = 0;
        double discountRate = 0;
        initialPrice = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the initial price total of the sale?"));
        commissionRate = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the percentage amount of the sales commission? \nFor example for 20%, type 20."));
        discountRate = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the customer's discount rate? \nFor example for a 15% discount, type 15."));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The final cost to the customer is \n$" + computeFinalPrice(initialPrice, commissionRate, discountRate) + ".");
    }
    public static String computeFinalPrice (double initialPrice, double commissionRate, double discountRate)
    {
        double finalPrice;
        DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        finalPrice = (initialPrice*(commissionRate+100)*.01)*((100-discountRate)*.01);      
        return (d.format(finalPrice));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, consider the following:

- For extra DRYness, you could have created a helper function to get a double

  ```
  private double getDouble( String msg )
  ```
- `computeFinalPrice` should probably be private
- If you wanted `computeFinalPrice` to be re-usable, then it probably makes more sense to return a double and keep it public
- A company would probably rather compute commission after discount, otherwise sales people will get really excited about giving 99% discounts ;)
- Either you initialize doubles with zeroes like in main() or you don't like in computeFinalPrice.
- As mentioned by another reviewer, consider Long instead of Double, as Doubles can have rounding issues.
- I would write

  ```
  finalPrice = (initialPrice*(commissionRate+100)*.01)*((100-discountRate)*.01);
  ```

  as

  ```
  `finalPrice = initialPrice*(commissionRate+100)*.01*(100-discountRate)*.01;`
  ```

  if I felt like messing with the code reviewer I might even

  ```
  `finalPrice = initialPrice*(commissionRate+100)*(100-discountRate)*.0001;`
  ```

Comment: Good point about making it private. It's for class, so I'm locked into applying the discount after the commission. I agree it makes little sense from a business perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note: Don't use floating point variables where you may need exact results:

- *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 48: Avoid float and double if exact answers are required*
- [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Fortunately Java has [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: I'm only a week into my first class so I'm still learning the ropes. I looked into BigDecimal after a few google searches. Since the program only takes a singular input for the output and only compounds once, I figured that the accuracy wouldn't matter too much. However, point taken. I'll school myself up on BigDecimal and use it from now on. Thanks for the feedback!